# Interpolating curve with dates on the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation

I've plotted a curve where the x axis is just dates using the datetime module, but I want to be able to interpolate between them. For example, I want to interpolate the value on 2017-05-05 even though I haven't put a value there. My code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


eudata = pd.read_csv("H:/euriborspots.csv")

months = eudata.ix[:, 'Expiry']
badspots = eudata.ix[:, 'Spot'] 
spots = [100 -x for x in badspots]


dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d').date() for d in months]
datearray = np.array(dates)
ratearray = np.array(spots)

ratecurve = plt.plot(datearray, ratearray)
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What kind of interpollation? Linear (draw the "best fit" line), polynomial, exponential, use a machine learning technique? Some are easier to do than others :)

Answer (score -1):

Interpolation is pretty broad topic. As usual, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) is a good place to start down the rabbit hole, if you're interested, though preferred methodologies tend to be very domain specific. In python, your options may be, listed in the order I would consider them:

**1. General Purpose Interpollation**

Python supports several techniques in the [scipy package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/interpolate.html)

For example, from the docs, 1D interpollation can be performed with

```
scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='linear'))
```

> Interpolate a 1-D function.
>
> x and y are arrays of values used to approximate some function f: y = f(x). This class returns a function whose call method use interpolation to find the value of new points.

The benefit of starting here is that it's a quick and easy launch place, requires minimal dependencies (included in Anaconda, e.g.), and supplies plenty of flexibility if you're looking to change your model later.

[Plotting code found in the docs:](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) and [in the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html#scipy.interpolate.splrep)

[image]  [image]

**2. Simple 1D Interpolation**

Simple 1D interpolation can also be found [right in numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html)

```
numpy.interp(x, xp, fp, )
```

> One-dimensional linear interpolation.
>
> Returns the one-dimensional piecewise linear interpolant to a function with > given values at discrete data-points.

The benefit of starting here is that you've probably already set up numpy if you're using matplotlib

**3. More Complex Interpolation**

The referenced Scipy package all typical use cases, but sometimes you want a model with even more generalizability. [Sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning) includes many powerful regression technqiues. For example, a [Gaussian Process](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html) allows for interpolation that includes an estimates of variance in addition to value. From the docs:

[image]

---

**Dealing with Dates**

If you're worried about dates not being easily inputted to most of these numerical methods, there are several [existing (python using datetimes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040291/how-to-do-interpolation-on-datetime-and-float) [(an example of conversion in matlab forums)](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42673-is-there-a-way-to-linearly-interpolate-dates-and-times) ways of doing this.